# Convert not valid date format to another in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, date-format, date-formatting

I have a date in Oracle format:

```
22-JAN 07
```

And i would like to convert it to something like this:

```
22/01
```

The problem is, i can not use the `date` function as the string I am trying to convert [doesn't match any valid date format.](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

I was trying it like this:

```
date('d/m', strtotime($row['BOOKED_DATE_FROM_1']))
```

But that shows:

```
01/01
```

How could i deal with this?
Thanks.

Comment: You could search and replace the date string, replace `JAN` with `01`, `FEB` with `02`, etc.  It wouldn't be elegant but it would work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Confirmed working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6OF3ck)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M y', '22-JAN 07');
echo $date->format('d/m');
```

Comment: +1. ....thus neatly demonstrating why PHP's modern `DateTime` class is so superior to the old date handling functions.

Comment: Is the Oracle date field using the DATE data type?  If yes, then this is not a true statement:   I have a date in Oracle format: 
22-JAN 07     The DATE in the database has no "format."  You can SELECT it into a string formatted how you want it:  TO_CHAR(date_col, 'DD/MM')     No need to convert in PHP.